# Any service that can do a location lookup that Tableau can understand?

Tags: geolocation, tableau-api

Tableau has a limited set of geographic roles (outside the US) that can be displayed on a choropleth map. I have a list of (Country, City) or (Country, District) pairs and I want to have it converted into a format that Tableau can read as a Geographic role.

Any service that can do that?

TIA

Comment: Tableau's online help has a nice chart listing the county equivalent for different countries. I haven't run into many international addresses for my own data but I hope the chart from Tableau can help you. It's at http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_data.html

Comment: Any service that generates Lat Lon will work. And current versions of Tableau can read mapping formats natively if you need more detail for small area chloropleths.